Logs for RDP desktop sharing
I have sporadic problems connecting to Ubuntu's built in Desktop Sharing on Ubuntu 24.04. If I reboot the server and log in locally, I can always connect, but if a day or two pass I usually can't. I'm connecting via RDP on Windows.
When it fails, it says the certificate is expired, I click connect anyway, and remote desktop window flashes on the screen then immediately quits.
I'm looking for logs on the server that might shed light on why this is. Where can I find them on Ubuntu?

Sorry, fixed the tag. I have Ubuntu desktop using the defaults: Wayland and gnome desktop

I am not sure if this is your problem. However, see this answer for the solution to local screen getting locked after not being used for a while.
